# Single command to remove user roles in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry, roles, user-roles, pcf, user-access-manager

I want to **remove all the roles assigned to the user**(Space auditor, space manager, org manager, ect.,) , **without deleting his ID with "cf delete-user"**, I want their ID still to exist with the uaac but remove all cloudfoundry roles alone, is there a code /command for that?

Comment: I mean as a admin I have access to all org/spcae and env, so is there any command like "cf remove-roles" that will remove all user roles for the user? or a way I can accomplish it with code or something

Comment: I don't believe the cf cli allows you to make multiple changes with one command, see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/getting-started.html#managing-roles, although you could script it if you wanted. I do think the v3 CAPI might allow this, although I haven't done it myself. The v3 API changes the way users are managed, see https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.126.0/index.html#roles and https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.126.0/index.html#users-and-roles-in-v3 which explains how it's changed from v2 -> v3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following command but it doesn't allow multiple roles in single command. However you can wrap these into a small script and can run it with different roles for desired user:

org level roles

```
cf unset-org-role USERNAME ORGANIZATION-NAME ROLE
```

where ROLE: OrgManager, BillingManager and OrgAuditor

space level roles:

```
cf unset-space-role USERNAME ORGANIZATION-NAME SPACE-NAME ROLE
```

where ROLE: SpaceManager, SpaceDeveloper and SpaceAuditor